# Old VB6 Application - Requires Old Custom Control Possible Sources

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration, farpoint-spread

So I have been given an old VB6b application that needs some minor modifications to get it working with a later version of SQL Server - however, It uses some 3rd party custom controls - Farpoint Spread and Input, Sheridan.

As this is really old - anyone knows of sources that can maybe obtain legacy versions of controls, so that I can make the fixes which are purely database driver code.

Comment: The Sheridan controls came with VB6, if I remember correctly on the 2nd CD. You should be able to get from MSDN if you have a subscription.

Comment: Thanks,  I have that one - the farpoint ones are the more difficult as they were used everywhere.    The current exe has the runtime dll's but causes problems because not designtime dll/license which makes editing or even attempting to upgrade difficult.

Comment: If you don't have the design time license you are going to struggle. Can you put SQL Server in to a 'compatible' mode?

Comment: Here is a link where you can [purchase the FarPoint controls](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadcom).

Comment: No I can't get it to work with the latest versions of SQL in its current form and it uses a really old version of MSDE.   The connection string code is really what I want to change and rebuild but without the custom controls I cant rebuild the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least one user running your application successfully, all the controls must be located on their PC. You can copy them from that location. Probably `Windows\SysWOW64\` folder.

If you are not sure of their location or even what the dependencies are, there are resources to figure that out. Personally I would start with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Comment: True but you may also need a .lic file (or something) in order to use the controls in the VB6 IDE i.e. in order to edit and build the application.

Comment: @MarkJ certainly that is a possibility. Perhaps the OP will be lucky and that won't be required. At the very least this approach can establish what the dependencies even are.

Comment: And that is my dilema.   I want to edit / rebuild the application - albiet not anything to do with screen layouts and I have all the runtime stuff but when rebuilding the .lic issue crops up.

Comment: @user3502865 if that is the main problem, your question does not mention it. You should really edit the question to clarify what you actually need.